# Form continous chain from a table SQL?

Tags: sql, qsqltablemodel

Consider the following SQL table (#forming):

| SeqNo | StartStep | EndStep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 788 | A | B |
| 788 | A | C |
| 795 | B | C |
| 797 | C | D |
| 798 | D | F |
| 798 | D | G |

```
Chain 1 : A  TO  B  TO  C  TO  D  TO  F 
Chain 2 : A  TO  B  TO  C  TO  D  TO  G 
Chain 3 : A  TO  C  TO  D  TO  F 
Chain 4 : A  TO  C  TO  D  TO  G
```

Expected output: So it would return all the above rows i.e. a total of 14 rows because of all the combinations:

| SeqNo | StartStep | EndStep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 788 | A | B |
| 795 | B | C |
| 797 | C | D |
| 798 | D | F |
| 788 | A | B |
| 795 | B | C |
| 797 | C | D |
| 798 | D | G |
| 788 | A | C |
| 797 | C | D |
| 798 | D | F |
| 788 | A | C |
| 797 | C | D |
| 798 | D | G |

Another example,

| SeqNo | StartStep | EndStep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 823 | A | B |
| 826 | B | C |
| 826 | B | D |
| 826 | B | E |
| 827 | D | F |
| 827 | D | E |
| 836 | E | C |
| 837 | C | G |

Chain 1 : A  TO  B  TO  C  TO G

Chain 2 : A  TO  B  TO  D  TO  F

Chain 3 : A  TO  B  TO  D  TO  E TO C TO G

Chain 4 : A  TO  B  TO  E  TO  C TO G

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| SeqNo | StartStep | EndStep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 823 | A | B |
| 826 | B | C |
| 837 | C | G |
| 823 | A | B |
| 826 | B | D |
| 827 | D | F |
| 823 | A | B |
| 826 | B | D |
| 827 | D | E |
| 836 | E | C |
| 837 | C | G |
| 823 | A | B |
| 826 | B | E |
| 836 | E | C |
| 837 | C | G |

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags, as the OP hasn't responded, and it is still unclear which RBDMS they are using.

Comment: Read https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/ and if you are running sqlserver add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNo) dr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SeqNo) rn
    FROM test
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT SeqNo, StartStep, EndStep, CAST(',' + StartStep + ',' + EndStep + ',' AS NVARCHAR) path, rn, 1 sn
    FROM cte1
    WHERE dr = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte1.SeqNo, cte1.StartStep, cte1.EndStep, CAST(cte2.path + cte1.EndStep + ',' AS NVARCHAR), cte2.rn, cte2.sn + 1
    FROM cte2
    JOIN cte1 ON cte2.EndStep = cte1.StartStep
    ),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT rn, MAX(sn) sn
    FROM cte2
    GROUP BY rn
    )
SELECT test.SeqNo, test.StartStep, test.EndStep
FROM cte2
JOIN cte3 ON cte2.rn = cte3.rn
         AND cte2.sn = cte3.sn
JOIN test ON CHARINDEX(',' + test.StartStep + ',' + test.EndStep + ',', cte2.path) > 0
ORDER BY cte2.path, test.SeqNo
;
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/ec39e9511c9ee3751981a6f2bc94381c/

Comment: thanks so much but im using SQL server management studio and it doesnt support RECURSIVE CTE . Is there another way to write this ??

Comment: @SabreenSageer SQL server management studio is client software for **SQL Server**.  Answer updated. PS. Execute `SELECT @@version;` and always provide this value in the question text.

Comment: Wow. it works thank you so much! yes from now on i will always provide this value in question text.

Comment: Why use `CHAR(1)` when you have words?

Comment: CREATE TABLE test (SeqNo INT, StartStep CHAR(1), EndStep CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(823, 'A', 'B'),
(826, 'B', 'C'),
(826, 'B', 'D'),
(826, 'B', 'E'),
(827, 'D', 'F'),
(827, 'D', 'E'),
(836, 'E', 'C'),
(837, 'C', 'G');
if this is the table above code is only giving me chain A->B->D->E>C->G
     
Actually there are 4 chains : 

1. A ,B,C,G  
2. A,B,D,F  
3. A,B,D,E,C,G  
4. A,B,E,C,G  

can someone check why above code does not work ?

Comment: @SabreenSageer Your data shows that the values for StartStep and EndStep are taken from some values list. This means that you must create separate table with these values and refer on them from your table. I.e. you will have numeric StartStepID and EndStepID columns, not char/varchar values.